# Hierarchical Cluster using dissimilarity matrix R

Tags: r, distance, hierarchical-clustering, r-daisy

I have mixed data type matrix **Data_string** size (947 x 41) that contain numeric and categorical attributes.

I produced a distance matrix (947 x 947) using the daisy() function and Gower distance measure in Rstudio.

```
d  <- daisy(Data_String, metric = "gower", stand = FALSE,type = list(symm = c("V1","V13") , asymm = c("V8","V9","V10")))
```

I applied hierarchical Cluster using dissimilarity matrix  (d).

```
# hclust
hc <- hclust(d, method="complete")
plot(hc)
rect.hclust(hc, 4)
cut <- cutree(hc, k = 1:5)
View(cut)

#Diana
d_as <- as.matrix(d)
DianaCluster <- diana(d_as, diss = TRUE, keep.diss = TRUE)
print(DianaCluster)
plot(DianaCluster)
```

The following is the plots I had.

[image: Diana_plot]

[image: hclust_plot]

** Note: I couldn't upload the image here since I do not have enough reputation's points.

I am struggling to understand the results, can anyone please

1- suggest any solution that I can apply in R to simplify the understanding of my results.

or

2- how I can link it to my source data, since all the results are based on the dissimilarity matrix.

Comment: Read a book about clustering methods? Or see [this link](http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~s133/Cluster2a.html) or [this](http://iasri.res.in/ebook/win_school_aa/notes/cluster_analysis_usingr.pdf) to get you started.

Comment: Thank you so much, I realised that the plot will be messy for understanding , so I used " cutree " function to get list of clusters instead of a tree plot.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at - 
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/130974/how-to-use-both-binary-and-continuous-variables-together-in-clustering

It explains how to use gower dissimilarity matrix with hclust. Hope this helps!